# Extract columns from list of coeftest objects

Tags: r, lapply

Is there a function that can extract two or more columns from a `coeftest` object? This is easy one `coeftest` object at a time, but can I do the same to a list (other than a `for()` loop)?

```
> # meaningless data
> temp <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100, mean = 5), b = rnorm(100, mean = 1),
+                    c = 1:100)
> formulas <- list(a ~ b, a ~ c)
> models <- lapply(formulas, lm, data = temp)
> library(lmtest)
> cts <- lapply(models, coeftest)

> # easy to extract columns one object at a time
> cts[[1]][, 1:2]
              Estimate Std. Error
(Intercept)  5.0314196  0.1333705
b           -0.1039264  0.0987044

> # but more difficult algorithmically
> # either one column
> lapply(cts, "[[", 1)
[[1]]
[1] 5.03142

[[2]]
[1] 5.312007

> # or two
> lapply(cts, "[[", 1:2)
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : attempt to select more than one element
```

Maybe the more fundamental question is if there is a way to turn the meat of the `coeftest` object into a data frame, which would allow me to extract columns singly, then use `mapply()`. Thanks!

Edit: I would like to end up with a matrices (or data frames) with the first and second columns.

```
    [[1]]
              Estimate Std. Error
(Intercept)  5.0314196  0.1333705
b           -0.1039264  0.0987044

[[2]]
                Estimate  Std. Error
(Intercept)  5.312007153 0.199485363
c           -0.007378529 0.003429477
```

Comment: Probably it is easier to answer if you provide a desired result.

Comment: @kohske -- Good call. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`[[` is the wrong subset function in this case. Note that when you `lapply()` over a list, what you are operating on are the components of the list, the bits you would get with `list[[i]]` where `i` is the ith component.

As such, you only need the `[, 1:2]` bit of `cts[[1]][, 1:2]` in the `lapply()` call. It is a little bit trickier because of the arguments for `[`, but easily doable with `lapply()`:

```
> lapply(cts, `[`, , 1:2)
[[1]]
                Estimate Std. Error
(Intercept)  4.926679544  0.1549482
b           -0.001967657  0.1062437

[[2]]
               Estimate  Std. Error
(Intercept) 4.849041327 0.204342067
c           0.001494454 0.003512972
```

Note the `<space>,` before `1:2`; this is the equivalent of `[ , 1:2]`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but how about:

```
> do.call("rbind", cts)[, 1:2]
                 Estimate  Std. Error
(Intercept)  4.8200993881 0.142381642
b           -0.0421189130 0.092620363
(Intercept)  4.7459340076 0.206372906
c            0.0005770324 0.003547885
```

Comment: @Kohkse -- Thanks! Right answer to a different question (I was slow to provide desired output), but this is a good tool for later.